# How to input to date format from a number

Tags: sas

I'm trying to put a number eg `20141001` into a date9. format eg `01OCT14`.
I've tried to use the input function with an input format of `yymmddn8.` but SAS throws out 'informat could not be found or loaded'

Any ideas how to get around this? (Sample code below)

```
data _null_;
  date=20141001;
  output=input(date,yymmddn8.);
  format output date9.;
  put output=;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.  Although there is a YYMMDDN format there is not an informat of the same name.  Use the YYMMDD informat. The Input function is expecting a character string i.e. the DATE variable. Redefine DATE as a character variable e.g.

```
data _null_;
  date='20141001';
  output=input(date,yymmdd8.);
  format output date9.;
  put output=;
run;
```

Alternatively you could have used these assignments:

```
output = input('20141001',yymmdd8.);
```

or

```
output = '01oct2014'd;
```